# How to change the color that a criteria is matched on?

Tags: pine-script

I want to test my strategy. The idea is that when 3 indicator values are above/below some point the strategy buy/sells, but for testing it just colors the bar that it would have sold/bought on and says the price it would have sold/bought on. I have tried to do it but it just colored the entire chart. How do i do this, i am new.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code so we can help.

Comment: @vitruvius i have tried 'barcolor(buyAccordingTo1 and buyAccordingTo2 and buyAccordingTo3 ? color.green : na) and
barcolor(sellAccordingTo1 and sellAccordingTo2 and sellAccordingTo3 ? color.red : na)' it is just a lot of ifs that set bools when the criteria is met, and it ither colors the entire chart or leaves it as na